# Is there a Google Voice API?

Tags: google-voice

Is there an API (officially or unofficially) for Google Voice? I would like to have an API to work with voicemails, send/receive SMS messages, initiate calls, etc.

What is the Android client using? Something internal? Has anyone documented it?

Comment: A question to ask Google. Voice is still rather in private testing and most of SO would not have an account on Google Voice.

Comment: You may also want to look into VoiceXML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VoiceXML

Comment: VoiceXML is not quite right, since Google Voice does almost no voice processing, just signaling and routing.

Comment: An official API is not out yet. But, if you want to experiment with other services similar to Google Voice, check out http://twilio.com or http://aws.amazon.com/sns/ (SMS).

Comment: Just a thought, there seems to be a C# Google Voice API. http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvoicedotnet/

Comment: For Java/Android there is GV4J: https://github.com/twyatt/gv4j

Comment: This is not an API, but is a Selenium nodejs script, and it works if you want to automatically send a small number of SMS messages using Google Voice: https://github.com/ourarash/autogvoice

Comment: A more maintained way to both send **and** receive SMS with Google Voice is to turn on emails in Voice settings and grab your data from there.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**No, there is no API for Google Voice announced as of 2021.**

"pygooglevoice" can perform most of the voice functions from Python.  It can send SMS.  I've developed code to receive SMS messages, but the overhead is excessive given the current Google Voice interface.  Each poll returns over 100K of content, so you'd use a quarter-gigabyte a day just polling every 30 seconds. There's a discussion on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/issues/detail?id=6) about this.

Comment: For reference: http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/

Comment: ~1 year later... still waiting for an official google voice api...

Comment: +1 year later...still not here.

Comment: it's almost 2010, come on google.....

Comment: annnd it's 2011. Still no API.

Comment: yeah still nothing... :(

Comment: Christmas 2011 and no Google Voice API in sight.

Comment: It is 2012.  No API.

Comment: Alas, pygooglevoice seems relatively inactive in terms of development and is plagued by many un-addressed issues.  I can't recommend it unless you are planning to hack on it yourself.

Comment: Did you checkout http://gvoicedotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Google currently offers this service free of charge. If there was an official api, it would be cost prohibitive. And it would be difficult to keep it free.  There was an iPhone app that took advantage of this to offer free sms but google shut that down... same reasoning.  I would guess once google starts charging for this service next year, they may release one.  My 2cent.  So please no more "2012. No API" comments... adds no value.

Comment: @samyi There are still iPhone and Android apps out there that allow GV users to send free SMS.  I think it is Apple that doesn't want its customers turning to Google for a service that they'd prefer to host (control).

Comment: But text messages are carrier based. Not Apple. When IP first came out several years ago, they had an app that piggybacked on google voice for all texts and thus eliminating the need to have a text plan. Google put a stop to that app due to increase in traffic.  An api would be very simple for google to release... it just doesn't make business sense.  Apple wouldn't have much say in apps using google... if they could they'd probably prevent google from releasing any apps in their ecosystem but they'd blemish their "draconian" reputation even further.  Not going to happen.

Comment: It's 2013... no API

Comment: It's over 9000... no API

Comment: Beware of time travelers.

Comment: Is it legal to use any unofficial API without a permission from Google?

Comment: The old Google Voice goes away May 14, 2014. A new, more locked-down system is replacing it. No more "third party apps".

Comment: It's 2014... no API

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21424377/1318946

Comment: It's April, still nothing.

Comment: Its already 2014.. Still No API.??

Comment: @JohnNagle Does that mean that pygooglevoice will no longer work? The latest version (0.5) is broken and abandoned and it sounds like there's no point in trying to revive it.

Comment: Almost 2015 here.. No API

Comment: It's 2015 and No API... oh wait, Google has been trying to incorporate voice into hangouts and it looks like hangouts DOES have an API https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/ - that one mentions google voice, at least for billing account balances. This is probably the place to start and where to direct your feature requests.

Comment: It's 3015 and Microsoft has taken over the world. Who would have guessed?

Comment: These comments are closed as not constructive by runnigAdithya♦

Comment: It's 2015 and there is still no google api

Comment: 2015 - truth has been spoken https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/interaction/voice-interactions

Comment: It's 2016... No API

Comment: Darn, I was a week late for the 2016 post...

Comment: Google announced Cloud Speech API two days ago: https://cloud.google.com/speech/ Does the wait pay off?

Comment: 2017, no api :(

Comment: Hangouts API does not allow to place calls.

Comment: 2017...We've gotten a redesign, but...no api.

Comment: its july 2017 & still waiting :-(

Comment: It's `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMM").format(new Date())` and No API

Comment: its near end of 2017... but no api.....

Comment: I can has API???

Comment: 2018, negative on the API

Comment: Twilio will give you a phone number with a voice & SMS api. https://www.twilio.com

Comment: 2018 NOOO API???

Comment: It is 2018. No API :(

Comment: it current year and no API :(

Comment: <?php echo 'It is ' . date("Y") . ' and no API.'; ?>

Comment: I think for sure by 2019 it'll be there.

Comment: It's 2035. The humans have all been destroyed by AI. But there is a Google Voice API. The AI use to text each other now that the humans are dead and they have nothing else to do.

Comment: Its 2998. Google has finally been defeated and Bing is on the rise. Google has finally re-vamped their Google Voice API from 2035 to compete with Bing Voice. Currently Google Voice API is down while the war of galaxies is occurring. This message was sent over a trillion Milky ways away, when you receive this, the year would be close to 9098. Good luck to the last human survivors, Mars has never been so friendly.

Comment: It is 2019. No API.

Comment: Guys, we can't say what would be now, it's over 10 years the question was asked, it's **2019**

Comment: It is 2020, No API yet !!!

Comment: Some people are eagerly waiting for new year to post a "NO API" comment on this thread.

Comment: It's 2021, and guess what? Still no API! (Sad Trombone Noise)

Comment: It's 2021... No API

Comment: It's Nov, 2021... No API

Comment: It's 2022 ... API?

Comment: I will set myself a Reminder for Jan 1, 2023 so I can come back here and post how Google Voice has no API.

Comment: its nearly the end of 2022, still.... NO API

Comment: It's 2023. No API :(

Comment: It is the end of time. No API.

Answer (score 7):

There is a C# Google Voice API... there is limited documentation, however the download has an application that 'works' using the API that is included:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/gvoicedotnet/

Comment: always gives login failed error :(

Answer (score 5):

Well...
These are PHP.
There is an sms one from google [here](http://code.google.com/p/phpgooglevoice/).

And github has one [here](https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API).

Another sms one is [here](http://kalinchuk.com/?p=44).  However, this one has a lot more code, so it may take up more space.

Answer (score 4):

I looked for a C/C++ API for Google Voice for quite a while and never found anything close
(the closest was a C# API).  Since I really needed it, I decided to just write one myself:

http://github.com/mastermind202/GoogleVoice

I hope others find it useful.  Feedback and suggestions welcome.

Comment: Its gone now. How did it work and where is it?

Comment: There's what looks like a fork of it (judging by the "MM" for "mastermind" signature on the README and the commit dates being right before this answer's 9/25/2010 date) here: https://github.com/siraj/GoogleVoice .

Answer (score 3):

Be nice if there was a Javascript API version. That way can integrate w/ other AJAX apps or browser extensions/gadgets/widgets.

Right now, current APIs restrict to web app technologies that support Java, .NET, or Python, more for server side, unless may use Google Web Toolkit to translate Java code to Javascript.

Comment: Duh, great idea, now for someone to do so. I may try when I have time, not anytime soon. But a JS port may be restricted by XmlHttpRequest limitations within browser. So it will still work best in other unrestricted JS environments like node.js, Windows Scripting Host, Rhino engine, and browser extensions/add-ons/widgets.

Comment: Done. I am the author of https://github.com/amper5and/node-google-voice.

Comment: thanks ampersand, I'll check out this JS implementation sometime.

Answer (score 3):

I needed a C# API and after spending hours looking for it (all I found was outdated and non-working) and unsuccessfully trying to port the PHP/Python/Java versions listed here (none worked either) I decided to create my own. It's SMS-only for now...

https://bitbucket.org/jitbit/sharpgooglevoice/wiki/Home