# Google Voice API Documentation

Tags: documentation, google-voice

I've spent the last hour searching for an official Google Voice API documentation but couldn't find anything but a bunch of API wrappers in `(insert your favorite programming language here)`.

Does a documentation for Google Voice's API not exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe Google has officially published an API yet.

You might want to refer to this post:
[Is there a Google Voice API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668619/is-there-a-google-voice-api)

Answer (score 8):

If you're okay with JavaScript you can take a look at their chrome extension, it gives you good idea on how to hack something together. For instance I've found this: http://google.com/voice/request/messages it gives you a list of messages in JSON
http://google.com/voice/request/user gives you your contacts and your GV number

Comment: +1 Cool! That got me hunting, also https://clients4.google.com/voice/request/unread will show new messages and stats, i think.

Answer (score 2):

unofficial, but has instructions for various languages and how to do some straight http requests:

[http://www.googlevoice.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130503230558/http://www.googlevoice.org/) (Web archive)

Comment: dead link ;-( the wayback machine at https://web.archive.org/ may be useful...

Answer (score 0):

It's time to migrate off Google Voice for applications. On May 14, 2014, Google will break the old interface.
https://plus.google.com/u/0/106636280351174936240/posts/MjyncJEbzxK

Google seems to be pushing Twilio as an alternative.  Twilio will be available from AppEngine.