# Integrating Google's voice call API in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-voice

I want to implement Google voice API in my ASP.NET application, such that where any user can call to any phone numbers like Google's voice call service. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668619/is-there-a-google-voice-api

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [GoogleVoice.NET](http://gvoicedotnet.sourceforge.net/).