# Google Voice API for Android

Tags: android, api, google-voice

Is there any API available for Google Voice on Android? I would like to be able to access the users Google Voice number and make phone calls from that number. I'm using this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, see this post [Is there a Google Voice API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668619/is-there-a-google-voice-api) It's been a long time coming and unfortunately still not here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unofficial Java API for Google Voice. However, its work fine.

https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/

Answer (score 0):

[GV4J](https://github.com/twyatt/gv4j) is an unofficial Google Voice API for Java.