# Android Google Voice Search changed language automatically sometimes

Tags: android, google-voice, android-search

I have successfully added Google Voice Search Activity using following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "Oops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
}
```

I searched in `"en-US"` and its worked perfectly but sometimes it is searching like **english of German or other countries and returning Pure ENGLISH WORDS.** and not recognize my language.

Is there any **SETTINGS** that makes my search better.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do much about it.