# Export Google voice call log to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-voice, google-voice-actions

I would like to know if there is a way to get my google voice call log to google sheets (received and missed calls)

I thought that maybe you can write a script in app script to export it and then make a trigger that should update it every night

that would be great

Thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668619/is-there-a-google-voice-api

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.